# Как добавить текст в SVG?

Tags: css, svg

Есть SVG демка https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gxMJOJ

Все блоки, как положено разделены на группы `<g>`, но текст описания, размещенный в `<desc>`  не отображается:

```
<g id="g10">
  <title>Заголовок 10</title>
  <desc>Текст 10</desc>
    <path id="path12" style="fill:#ffffff;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:#231f20;
    stroke-width:1;stroke-linecap:butt;
    stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:10;
    stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1" 
    d="M 491.232,389.335 H 66.082 v 225.549 h 425.15 z" />
</g>
```

И ещё не нашёл информации как выравнивать текст внутри SVG-блока?

Comment: Насколько знаю, title и desc в svg и не должны отобраться. Они используются лишь для указания описания ваших svg

Comment: @Cheg ну title да отображается как всплывающая подсказка при наведении, desc вообще непонятно где

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Теги `<desc> ... </desc>` можно добавлять в любое место svg кода.
   Это своего рода поясняющий текст, в котором можно разместить, что
   угодно, от комментарий до ссылок и всё это не будет видно
   пользователю на дисплее, но поисковики, особенно Google хорошо
   индексируют содержание в этих тегах.
2. Теги `<title>... </title>` выступают в роли тултипа. Наведите курсор
   на блок и должен появиться текст, который размещен в этих тегах.
   Тоже индексируется.
3. Текст добавляется в svg c помощью тегов `<text> .... </text>`
   Внутри файла SVG позиционирование текста абсолютно при этом указывается координаты X, Y начала текста. 
   Ваш пример я прогнал через [SVG оптимизатор](https://petercollingridge.appspot.com/svg-editor) для уменьшения кода и лучшего понимания.

```html
<svg  xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 300 794 1123"  style="border:1px solid red;">
 
  <g id="g10">
    <title>
      Заголовок 10
    </title>
    <desc>
      Текст 10
    </desc>
  <text x="200" y="360"  fill="black" font-family="Verdana, serif" font-size="24" font-weight="900"> Заголовок 10</text> 
  
    <path id="path12" d="M491 389H66v226h425z" style="fill:#fff;stroke:#231f20"/> 
 <text x="80" y="410" fill="grey" font-size="18" font-weight="900"> Текст 10
 <tspan dx="10">Текст 10 </tspan>
 <tspan dx="10">Текст 10 </tspan>
 <tspan dx="10">Текст 10 </tspan>
 <tspan dx="10">Текст 10 </tspan>
 <tspan dx="-400" dy="20">Текст 10 </tspan>
 </text>
  </g> 
  
  <g id="g11">
    <title>
      Заголовок 11
    </title>
 
 
    <desc>
      Текст 11
    </desc>
    <path id="path14" d="M253 470H72v138h181z" style="fill:#fff;stroke:#231f20"/>
  <text x="90" y="490"  fill="black" font-family="Verdana, serif" font-size="18" font-weight="900"> Заголовок 11</text> 
  
  <text x="80" y="520" fill="grey" font-size="18" font-weight="300"> Текст 11 Текст 11 
 <tspan dx="-130" dy="20">Текст 11 </tspan>
 <tspan dx="0">Текст 11 </tspan>
</text>
  </g>
  <g id="g12">
    <title>
      Заголовок 12
    </title>
    <desc>
      Текст 12
    </desc>
    <path id="path16" d="M482 470H261V608H482Z" style="fill:#fff;stroke:#231f20"/>
 
  <text x="300" y="490"  fill="black" font-family="Verdana, serif" font-size="18" font-weight="900"> Заголовок 12</text> 
  
   <text x="300" y="520" fill="grey" font-size="18" font-weight="300"> Текст 12 Текст 12 
 <tspan dx="-130" dy="20">Текст 12 </tspan>
 <tspan dx="0">Текст 12 </tspan>  
 
 </text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

В svg нет автоматического переноса текста, как в Html поэтому приходится применять относительное позиционирование с помощью тегов `<tspan> .. </tspan>`, которые имеют атрибуты `dx`и `dy` относительного смещения текста по координатам.

```
<text x="80" y="410" fill="grey" font-size="18" font-weight="900"> Текст 10
        <tspan dx="10">Текст 10 </tspan>
        <tspan dx="10">Текст 10 </tspan>
        <tspan dx="10">Текст 10 </tspan>
        <tspan dx="10">Текст 10 </tspan>
        <tspan dx="-400" dy="20">Текст 10 </tspan>
        </text>
```

**Позиционирование текста с помощью атрибута `text-anchor`**

```html
 <svg  xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 200 200" height="200" width="200" style="border:1px solid red;">
 
 <line x1="100" y1="5" x2="100" y2="195" stroke="dodgerblue" />
 <g fill="black" font-family="Verdana, serif" font-size="24" font-weight="900">
 
 <text x="100" y="60"  style="text-anchor: start;"> Start </text>
<text x="100" y="110" style="text-anchor: Middle;">  middle </text>
<text x="100" y="160"  style="text-anchor: end;">  End </text>    
 </g>
 
 </svg>
```

Comment: Супер, спасибо, вопрос только в данном случае как вы подобрали координаты заголовков оптимальные, что бы они прямо по середине стояли, например x="300" y="490". В редактор какой-то эту svg загнали? Не руками же? А вообще надписи должны идти вместе с файлом из редактора?

Comment: @fosh4455, как это не парадаксально, но делал руками, для меня это было быстрее, но это от опыта зависит. Вообще в Incscape есть такая возможность, выбираете кнопку "Т" - текст, выбираете место на канвасе и вводите нужный текст. Но после Incscape много лишнего мусора, поэтому дополнительно нужно прогонять через оптимизатор.

Comment: спасибо, да Incscape мне тоже не понравился. Вопрос по адаптивности только остался, как задачать x,y для текста что бы и текст и блоки оставались пропорционально на своих местах относительно друг друга, т.е. сжималось или расширялось всё вместе?

Comment: @Сделал адаптивным

Comment: @fosh4455 для адаптивности в шапке svg файла необходимо установить значения  width="100%" height="100%" или просто удалить их, так как они по умолчанию итак равны 100%