# Полное позиционирование по вертикали и горизонтали SVG текста

Tags: html, css, svg

Вопросы по позиционированию SVG текста, в той или иной форме, уже задавались. Например: [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/698072/28748) и [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/700984/28748). 
Но хотелось бы получить полный ответ в сжатой, доступной форме с примерами о наиболее употребляемых способах позиционирования, вертикального и горизонтального выравнивания SVG текста внутри SVG файла.

Известно, что даже современные браузеры, такие как Chrome, Firefox, Opera по разному поддерживают атрибуты команды `<text>`, отвечающие за позиционирование.
Например: `text-anchor="middle"` поддерживается одинаково разными браузерами, но другой атрибут `alignment-baseline="middle"` Chrome поддерживает полностью, а Firefox частично.
В качестве примера позиционирование приведу использование  `text-anchor`

```html
<svg  xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 200 200" height="200" width="200" style="border:1px solid red;">
 
 <line x1="100" y1="5" x2="100" y2="195" stroke="dodgerblue" />
 <g fill="black" font-family="Verdana, serif" font-size="24" font-weight="900">
 
 <text x="100" y="60"  style="text-anchor: start;"> Start </text>
<text x="100" y="110" style="text-anchor: Middle;">  middle </text>
<text x="100" y="160"  style="text-anchor: end;">  End </text>    
 </g>
 
 </svg>
```

Answer (score 2):

Пример использования атрибута `text-anchor` для горизонтального позиционирования и атрибута `alignment-baseline` для вертикального позиционирования:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xml:space="preserve"
         width="640" height="250"     viewBox="0 0 640 250"  >
  
 <defs>
  <pattern id="newPattern" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
    x="0" y="0" width="10" height="10"
    viewBox="0 0 10 10" >
    
   <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="10" y2="0" stroke="#c3c3c3" fill="none"  />
   <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="10" stroke="#c3c3c3" fill="none"  />
  </pattern>
 </defs>

 <!-- Background -->
 <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#newPattern)" />

 <!-- Lines and dots -->
 <circle cx="80" cy="120" r="4" fill="orange"  />
 <line x1="0" y1="120" x2="100%" y2="120" stroke="black" opacity=".6" />
 
 <circle cx="80" cy="170" r="4" fill="orange"  />
 <line x1="0" y1="170" x2="100%" y2="170" stroke="black" opacity=".6" />
 
 <line x1="0" y1="70" x2="100%" y2="70" stroke="black" opacity=".6" />
 <circle cx="80" cy="70" r="4" fill="orange"  />
 
 <line x1="0" y1="220" x2="100%" y2="220" stroke="black" opacity=".6" />
 
 <!-- text-anchor samples -->
 <text x="80" y="30" font-size="20" text-anchor="middle">text-anchor</text>
  <text x="80" y="70" fill="blue" font-size="20" text-anchor="start" >start</text>
  <text x="80" y="120" fill="blue" font-size="20" text-anchor="middle" >middle</text>
  <text x="80" y="170" fill="blue" font-size="20" text-anchor="end" >end</text>
 
 <!-- alignment-baseline samples -->
 <text x="400" y="30" font-size="20" text-anchor="middle">alignment-baseline</text>
 
  <text x="160" y="70" fill="blue" font-size="20" alignment-baseline="auto" >auto</text>
  <text x="280" y="70" fill="blue" font-size="20" alignment-baseline="baseline" >baseline</text>
  <text x="400" y="70" fill="blue" font-size="20" alignment-baseline="middle" >middle</text>
  <text x="520" y="70" fill="blue" font-size="20" alignment-baseline="central" >central</text>
  
  <text x="160" y="120" fill="blue" font-size="20" alignment-baseline="before-edge" >before-edge</text>
  <text x="400" y="120" fill="blue" font-size="20" alignment-baseline="text-before-edge" >text-before-edge</text>
  
  <text x="160" y="170" fill="blue" font-size="20" alignment-baseline="after-edge" >after-edge</text>
  <text x="400" y="170" fill="blue" font-size="20" alignment-baseline="text-after-edge" >text-after-edge</text>
  
  <text x="160" y="220" fill="blue" font-size="20" alignment-baseline="ideographic" >ideographic</text>
  <text x="280" y="220" fill="blue" font-size="20" alignment-baseline="alphabetic" >alphabetic</text>
  <text x="400" y="220" fill="blue" font-size="20" alignment-baseline="hanging" >hanging</text>
  <text x="520" y="220" fill="blue" font-size="20" alignment-baseline="mathematical" >mathematical</text>
</svg>
```

В Chrome всё работает, как написано в [спецификации w3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/text.html#DominantBaselineProperty).
Firefox и Opera поддерживают `alignment-baseline`  частично, только для элементов:

`<tspan>
<tref>
<altglyph>
<textpath>`